# airflow API get all unpaused/running dags

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-api

How do I get a list of all unpaused(running) dags using airflow API?
I tried `GET /dags` endpoints but I did not find a query string to filter paused dags, isn't there something like `is_paused`  query parameter or body parameter perhaps?
P.S I'm currently using airflow version 2.2.3 +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Airflow API doesn't support this filter, you should get all the dags and filter them locally.

If you really need this filter, you can create an [Airflow plugin](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/plugins.html) which exposes a simple API to fetch the unpaused dags and return them.

Update: this filter will be available in Airflow API from 2.6.0 ([PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/28713))

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is plugin made for this. You can fetch the dags along with status. Please explore this plugin. May be this is what you are looking for.

[Airflow API Plugin](https://github.com/airflow-plugins/airflow_api_plugin)

[Dag Run Endpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7yJp.png)

Or else you can write your custom python script/API to fill the dagbag and then filter the list to get the list of dags with status which you want.